# Непонятный атрибут у тэга

Tags: веб-программирование, теги, html

Этот вопрос именно по HTML. Читаю сейчас [это](http://javatutor.net/books/tiej/jsp). в разделе "Манипуляция сессиями в JSP" есть листинг "SessionObject.jsp". В конце этого листинга есть непонятный мне код - я не понимаю, что означает атрибут **type** у тэга **form**. Значение, вроде, похоже на метод, однако, несмотря на это, всегда приходит метод get.  [Вот тут смотрел](http://htmlbook.ru/html/form) - никаких подсказок. В гугле тоже, вроде, пусто.

```
<FORM TYPE=POST ACTION=SessionObject2.jsp>
<INPUT TYPE=submit name=submit Value="Invalidate"></FORM>

<FORM TYPE=POST ACTION=SessionObject3.jsp>
<INPUT TYPE=submit name=submit Value="Keep Around"></FORM>
```

Comment: @argamidon, судя по оформлению, по html стоит читать отдельный ресурс.

Comment: Код не мой. я знаю, выглядит страшно, просто скопировал из книги.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, тут имелось в виду ***METHOD***

Answer (score 2):

В атрибуте method (не type) указывается метод передачи данных на сервер.

[Тут](http://dayte2.com/get-post-methods) можете почитать про два основных метода передачи данных на сервер.